# Add html code to blogdown website created in R

Tags: html, r, blogdown

I would like to add the following html code to my blogdown website so all of the pages can be generated on the intranet in Internet Explorer.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

The code works, however I don't know how or where to add it because whenever I generate the website using `blogdown::serve_site()`, the code disappears.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest part is to edit the template that generates your website.

If you go to `layouts/partials` you can look for a file that sets the header information. The name of the relevant file depends on your theme. An often-used name is `header.includes.html`.

Add your line to that file.

If you do not have anything there then look at

`themes/yourtheme/layouts/partials/`

where `yourtheme` is the name of the theme that you are using. Copy the relevant file to `layouts/partials` and follow the steps above.

Comment: Or, if you don't know how to do it, you may file a request to the theme author (on Github or somewhere).